# How do I write a python code with PyPred?

Tags: python

I need to write a simple code with grammar of [PyPred](https://github.com/armon/pypred#grammar)

```
if (country == 'Russia' or city = 'Moscow') and message == 'How to catch taxi':
    print('You can catch taxi here: link')
```

I tried this but I don't think it's right

```
def function(place, message):
    if Predicate("(place is 'Russia' or place is 'Moscow') and message contains 'how to catch taxi'"):
        return "You can catch taxi here: link"
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you "don't think it's right"?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: `p = Predicate(...)` creates your rules and then those rules must be applied via something like `p.analyze(message)`

Comment: I think predicate() just creates an object and doesn't return true/false

Comment: so p.analyze() returns true/false. right?